# error magento 2: FilesystemIterator::__construct(/var/www/html/pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/Magento): failed to open dir: Permission denied

Tags: magento2, error, cache, static-content

I'm getting error when , going to clear cache from backend admin.
'**flush static cache** '( Preprocessed view files and static files) button only.

Because of this error i'm not able to clear static files, like css

Full error was:

```
FilesystemIterator::__construct(/var/www/html/pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/Magento): failed to open dir: Permission denied
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(398): FilesystemIterator->__construct('/var/www/html/p...', 12288)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(402): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteDirectory('/var/www/html/p...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(402): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteDirectory('/var/www/html/p...')
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php(175): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteDirectory('/var/www/html/p...')
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/State/CleanupFiles.php(105): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write->delete('_requirejs')
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/State/CleanupFiles.php(66): Magento\Framework\App\State\CleanupFiles->emptyDir('static')
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Cache/CleanStaticFiles.php(20): Magento\Framework\App\State\CleanupFiles->clearMaterializedViewFiles()
#7 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Cache/CleanStaticFiles/Interceptor.php(25): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\CleanStaticFiles->execute()
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\CleanStaticFiles\Interceptor->execute()
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\CleanStaticFiles\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Backend...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\CleanStaticFiles\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\CleanStaticFiles\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Backend...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\CleanStaticFiles\Interceptor), Array, 'designLoader')
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/Design.php(39): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\Design->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\CleanStaticFiles\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Backend...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\CleanStaticFiles\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\CleanStaticFiles\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\CleanStaticFiles\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(140): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#25 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Cache/CleanStaticFiles/Interceptor.php(40): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\CleanStaticFiles\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\CleanStaticFiles\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(140): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#34 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#37 /var/www/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
```

Comment: You should be set permission 777 for `pub` folder

Comment: should i set to pub ? or just pub/static?

Answer (score 0):

yes this help me:

> sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/pub/static/*

Comment: You should NEVER use 777 permission in Product Environments. Stay away from using this and check this Doc for Permission handling in Magento: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html